# Initializing generic T class

Tags: java, generics

I might be understanding this wrong, I have multiple classes, for example:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3

They all extend the same parent class and need the same constructor arguments, I want to be able to call a method like below passing say Item1.class as the parameter, it then returns a new instance of Item1.

`private <T extends ParentClass> T getItem(Class<T> itemType) {`

After the method has collected the relevant data for the item's constructor, can I use `itemType.newInstance()` to create a new instance? If so how do I pass arguments to it's constructor?

Comment: Try using a functional interface + method reference instead of a class object. For instance, if the constructors only take a string: `private <T extends ParentClass> T getItem(Function<String, T> constructor)`. You can then call it as `getItem(Item1::new)` etc. If the constructors take two arguments you can use `BiConsumer`, otherwise you can easily create your own functional interface.